# Damp proofing a single-skin outbuilding for batten & insulation

Tags: insulation, brick, damp-proof-course

I have a small outbuilding (~2m x 4.5m) which I currently use for storing tools and my bicycle. It's a semi-detached single-skin construction with a concrete roof, concrete floor and single-skin brick for the walls. The roof is currently leaking, which means the inside is currently quite humid, but I intend on getting this felted over once the current Covid-19 restrictions have been lifted in the UK. As a result of this humidity, some of my tools have gone rusty and some of my wood scraps have gone mouldy.

Later on this year once the roof is fixed I intend to try and convert this space into a small workshop for woodwork and electronics. As part of this, I intend on battening the walls and using 25mm insulation board (with aluminium covering, likely Kingspan TP10), trying to insulate as best as I can while remaining mindful that I don't have much space to play with. I'm confident enough to carry all the woodwork, including replacing the door frame, but I'm not sure how I should go about damp-proofing the interior to protect the battens and plasterboard.

Other than the leaky roof I don't believe there is a damp problem elsewhere, the paint I applied the to the bricks two years ago still seems in good condition and not mouldy or flaky. Ventilation isn't an issue as there is a window that I usually leave partially open on night-vent.

To my knowledge my options are to either:

- Use a liquid damp-proof membrane or tanking slurry, which if applied correctly would prevent damp from reaching the internal side of the concrete and brick

or

- Apply a damp proof membrane along the floor and walls. However this still has the potential of allowing water to pool between the membrane and the brick/concrete.

What would be the best way for a DIY'er like myself, taking into account cost and ease of application?

Here's a proposed layout, showing the issue with the battens when damp proofing is not used.
[image: proposed diagram]

Answer (score 0):

To get accurate information, this web site may help:

[Ubakus.de](https://www.ubakus.de/u-wert-rechner/?)

By inputting all existing and planned layers, possible problems will be shown in a second.

**Experimenting/researching is easy** by switching on/off of layers.

R-value can be shown by clicking on the spanner/tool icon next to the U-value.

It is by far the most professional and sophisticated site to calculate and visualize the relevant insulation parameters that I have found up to now.

It is **free** for private use.

Fastest way is to choose an adequate **example (menu)** and to edit the layers.

Comment: Good resource, it proves my fears of moisture getting in through the battens are well founded. However it doesn't really answer my question as it doesn't give me any recomendations as to how to remedy this. Likewise, it doesn't address my concerns about the concrete floor either.

Comment: Yes, the site does only analyze. May be adding a screenshot of the layers may help to get some useful information from experienced readers that are familiar with the local codes and available materials. A shed without heating is a special situation. A timer- controlled fan ( fan from old PC, old mobile phone power supply, night only) which blows cold dry air into the shed could help to keep the moisture level low.

Comment: Have added the diagram to my question. A powered fan is an option as I'm also planning to install a solar power storage system.

Comment: Indoor insulation is easy to install, but the downside is the moisture problem inside the wall.
Shifting the insulation layer to the outside (covering the brick walls) surely would ease the moisture problem, but the installation is more complicated since it has to be weatherproofed.

Comment: I just saw that only the pine wood seems to be the problem.
Pine has a lower heat transfer resistance compared to the PUR foam.
Maybe the pine boards could be replaced by PUR foam to get a pure PUR foam insulation? There are PUR foam boards that are very rigid and strong.

Comment: Would the lack of wooden battens present further problems though? i.e. being unable to mount things like shelves, and being unable to mount plasterboard? Would treated wood (i.e. suitable for outdoor use) be a better option? I only used pine as an example.

Comment: Shelves that are standing on the ground probably would rob too much space, but would only need 2 long standard dowels in the wall to keep them from falling - if any.

Otherwise there are special long dowels (full metal) that can withstand that long lever through the PUR foam for a hanging shelf.

What could be tested on the site: different wood type, thinner PUR foam (and/or thicker wood) in order to match the same heat transfer resistance, shifting the insulation to the outside, adding damp stop foils.